# Flutter firebase auth login is not updating to home page

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update the home of `MaterialApp` widget depending on whether the user has sign up or not.
Below is the code inside the state of ``MaterialApp```

```
String? _userUid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      //print('changed');
      print(user?.uid);
      updateUser(user?.uid);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateUser(String? USER_UID) {
    setState(() {
      _userUid = USER_UID;
    });
  }
```

Below is the code for the home property

```
home: _userUid == null ? const Onbaording2() : const HomeScreen(),
```

Somewhere inside the widget tree

```
final user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email!,
        password: password!,
      );
```

After running the code above, there is a user created in firebase but the screen does not change.

Also the signOut works perfectly by signing me out when I use `firebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`

Answer (score 0):

even if you change your variable it will not be redirected to the home screen because materialapp is only called when you first load or restart the app so rather than adding this condtion in home page or other way can be

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      //print('changed');
      print(user?.uid);
      if(user == null){ navigate to onboarding }
      else{ navigate to home page  }
      
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```